# jaxws:wsgen fails to find Web Service

Tags: maven, jax-ws

I have the jaxws-maven-plugin set up in the following way:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-wsdl-for-random-num-generator</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsgen</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sei>mydomain.sib.RandomNumberGeneratorEndpoint</sei>
                        <destDir>${basedir}\wsdls\</destDir>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I try to run:

```
mvn jaxws:wsgen
```

I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.2:w
sgen (default-cli) on project soap-ws: No @javax.jws.WebService found. -> [Help
1]
```

The mydomain.sib.RandomNumberGeneratorEndpoint does have the @javax.jws.WebService annotation:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "mydomain.RandomNumberGenerator")
public class RandomNumberGeneratorEndpoint implements RandomNumberGenerator {

        public double getRandomNumber(long limit) {
            return Math.random() * limit;
        }

}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with my setup?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the issue was rather simple: I missed the *genWsdl* tag from the plugin setup.

The setup now looks like:

```
    <configuration>
            <sei>mydomain.sib.RandomNumberGeneratorEndpoint</sei>
            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
            <resourceDestDir>${basedir}\wsdls\randomNumberGenerator</resourceDestDir>
    </configuration>
```

I did see this tag when I was reading through the documentation [here](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsgen-mojo.html) - but I did not realize that was the problem... I dropped the ball.

Thanks anyway and hope this answer is useful for someone some day.